# Dark theme on YouTube when bookmarked

Tags: youtube, google-chrome, bookmarks

I want to bookmark Youtube such that every time I  open it on google chrome in incognito mode, it opens up with the dark theme already applied.

Side note: The dark theme is applied if I open a new tab in incognito mode and type Youtube.com if I had already applied it in the previous tab.

P.S. : I live on the outskirt of USA and I have an ISP of Canada(because it was cheap). So every time I type youtube.com, it opens up on the Canada server, to avoid this I bookmarked Youtube with the location changed to US and it opens up on the US server(works in incognito).

Is there a similar way for dark theme as well?

Answer (score 2):

This solution seems to work for me:

`https://www.youtube.com/?gl=US&theme=dark`

The query string in the above link: `gl=US&theme=dark` sets the location to `US` and theme to `dark`

Try creating a bookmark with the above URL and see if that does what you're after.